# add trailing slash after removing .html extention

Tags: html, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My website is **non www**, it has **wordpress in subdirectory** and some static webpages in the **root** and **other subdirectory**.

I want to

1. remove .html extention from the webpages in the root and
   the others static webpages in subdirectory,
2. add slash at the end,
3. 301 redirect from non slash to URL with slash.

so it should be

`http://example.com/articles.html` to `http://example.com/articles/`

and

`http://example.com/subdirectory/book.html` to `http://example.com/subdirectory/book/`

The below code

1. Is working with non slash at the end.
2. Redirects 301 URL with slash to non.

Here's my .htaccess:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>     
 Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews


RewriteEngine On     
RewriteBase /

#removing trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L]

#www to non
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(([a-z0-9_]+\.)?example\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .? http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

#html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f     
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]

#index redirect 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.html\ HTTP/     
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ http://example.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.html     
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L] 
</IfModule>
```

Everything is ok with the wordpress, the problem is with static pages only.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/ might be more appropriate

Comment: What error are you getting when you enter `http://domain.com/articles.html` in browser?

Comment: it redirect me to http://domain.com/articles

Comment: Here's my Original link before stripping html
http://ghadaalsaman.com/articles.html
or
http://ghadaalsaman.com/articles.html/
both of them redirect 301 to 
http://ghadaalsaman.com/articles

and i want to add slash at the end